# Java, convert Byte Array to HashMap or JSON string

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, hashmap

I'm making an Android App to manage a Unix computer remotely. The application also allows you to see real-time PC statistics (CPU temperature, CPU load, etc.). On the pc there is a Python server that through a socket sends a JSON string as a byte array to the app which contains the PC statistics, like this:

```
[123, 45, 67, 90, ...]
```

This is the contents of the byte array (I decoded it with a website):

```json
{
    "author": "Anton",
    "type": "server info",
    "date": "08/01/2021",
    "content": "",
    "opt": {
        "cpu": {
            "freq": [3866.041875, 1600.0, 3900.0],
            "usage": [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0],
            "load": [0.5, 0.63, 0.61]
        },
        "memory": {
            "ram": [15.54, 12.01, 22.7, 2.85, 9.67]
        },
        "disks": {
            "ssd": [219.1, 13.0, 194.9, 6.3],
            "hdd": [0.0, 0.0, 0, 100.0]
        },
        "temps": {
            "core-0": [32.0, 85.0, 105.0],
            "core-1": [36.0, 85.0, 105.0],
            "core-2": [37.0, 85.0, 105.0],
            "core-3": [38.0, 85.0, 105.0]
        }
    },
    "attached": null
}
```

How can I transform the byte array into a structure like a `HashMap` or a JSON string, so that I can retrieve the PC statistics, and then view them in the App through ProgressiveBars?

Comment: Are you asking how to decode the byte array into a JSON string like you've already provided? Or are you asking about converting the JSON string you provided (decoded from the website) into a Java structure like a HashMap?

Comment: I should convert the byte array into a HashMap, or in any case a structure that allows me to retrieve every single data of it.

Comment: @DanieleMonaldi "JSON string as a byte array" is not clear. Does `[123, 45, 67, 90, ...]` represent the data logically (i.e., the first byte is value of 123, and so on), or does it represent the data physically (i.e., literally `[`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `,`, ... go over your network)?

Comment: @fluffy the server sends me the JSON string like the one I published in the form of a byte array, so for example 123 represents the character "{"

Comment: @DanieleMonaldi I have an idea of decoding it using Gson, but let me ask you three questions first. 1) `123`, `45`, `67`, and `90` represent ASCII/UTF-8 characters `{`, `-`, `C`, and `Z` respectively (malformed but unusual JSON): they differ structurally from the JSON, but why? 2) When I was pretty-formatting your JSON, I found it was illegal: is that something your server sends to you or you just had some typos while posting it? 3) Shouldn't your server send a ready-to-use JSON rather than send it as an byte-array-encoded JSON that is not necessarily JSON-compatible?

Comment: @DanieleMonaldi And the fourth one please: 4) You mentioned an online decoder. Which did you use?

Comment: The byte array I posted was a generic example, with random numbers, just to give the idea. The json, instead, is a real example.  Unfortunately the server was not developed by me, but being a group project it was developed by a friend, who chose this solution because it also works with iOS (an app that another friend is developing). I used this site: https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-bytes-to-utf8

Comment: @DanieleMonaldi I do not want to seem intrusive, but shouldn't the friend of yours fix their Python code so that the serve could generate legal and valid JSON ready to consume in _any_ application (including commands `curl` and `jq`), and another friend of yours (at the iOS side) could remove away the intermediate code that decodes byte-array-encoded text to plain text? Having that, you could even avoid asking the question here, because now you have to deal with bad design and implement an adapter to decode one stream to another one.

Comment: I think it is the only solution, thanks for the help!

Comment: @fluffy The server has been fixed and now sends a json. Now how should I do to retrieve the information?

Comment: @DanieleMonaldi One less issue now so good news! It depends on which JSON library you're using, but I guess there are more comprehensive sources over the Web than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) from Jackson or any other JSON parser/serializer to achieve this. One option, using ObjectMapper is to just serialize the string directly into a hashmap like this:

```
byte src[] = getBytesFromServer();
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> tr = new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> {};
Map<String,Object> val = om.readValue(src,tr);
```

There are a few variants of this that should be helpful to you. You can also achieve the same with other JSON libraries like [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: A small edit on the 3rd line to correct the syntax - 




TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> tr = new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> () {};

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, while your server code is not yet fixed, I can provide an example of adapting the byte-encoded response to what you can parse, for the "educational" purposes to avoid bad practices in the future (simply don't do the following).

The idea to solve your problem is *adapting* the incoming payload (byte-array-encoded text) to a byte/character-stream that can be consumed as JSON.

Using the org.json is *might* be implemented like this (however, I'm not sure if I've implemented it properly):

```java
public final class Decoding {

    private Decoding() {
    }

    public static Reader of(final Reader reader) {
        final JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(reader);
        return new Reader() {
            private boolean beginToProcess = true;
            private boolean endToProcess = true;

            @Override
            public int read(@Nonnull final char[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)
                    throws IOException {
                if ( beginToProcess ) {
                    final char ch = jsonTokener.nextClean();
                    if ( ch != '[' ) {
                        throw new IOException("Not an array begin: " + ch);
                    }
                    beginToProcess = false;
                }
                if ( !jsonTokener.more() ) {
                    if ( endToProcess ) {
                        final char ch = jsonTokener.nextClean();
                        if ( ch != '\u0000' ) {
                            throw new IOException("Not an array or document end: " + ch);
                        }
                        endToProcess = false;
                    }
                    return -1;
                }
                final char b = (char) (int) jsonTokener.nextValue();
                if ( jsonTokener.more() ) {
                    final char ch = jsonTokener.nextClean();
                    switch ( ch ) {
                    case ',':
                    case ']':
                        // do nothing
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IOException("Not an array delimiter: " + ch);
                    }
                }
                buffer[offset] = b;
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void close()
                    throws IOException {
                reader.close();
            }
        };
    }
    ...
```

or using Gson for example:

```java
    ...
    public static Reader of(final JsonReader jsonReader) {
        return new Reader() {
            private boolean beginToProcess = true;
            private boolean endToProcess = true;

            @Override
            public int read(@Nonnull final char[] buffer, final int offset, final int length)
                    throws IOException {
                if ( beginToProcess ) {
                    jsonReader.beginArray();
                    beginToProcess = false;
                }
                if ( !jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                    if ( endToProcess ) {
                        jsonReader.endArray();
                        endToProcess = false;
                    }
                    return -1;
                }
                final int b = jsonReader.nextInt();
                buffer[offset] = (char) b;
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void close()
                    throws IOException {
                jsonReader.close();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Both decoders are suboptimal and do not provide the maximum performance, but I hope you won't need it once your server is fixed. Now you can decode the input readers and convert them to valid JSON documents (in a JUnit 5 test):

```java
public final class DecodingTest {

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        final String payload = "[123,34,97,117,116,104,111,114,34,58,34,65,110,116,111,110,34,44,34,116,121,112,101,34,58,34,115,101,114,118,101,114,32,105,110,102,111,34,44,34,100,97,116,101,34,58,34,48,56,47,48,49,47,50,48,50,49,34,44,34,99,111,110,116,101,110,116,34,58,34,34,44,34,111,112,116,34,58,123,34,99,112,117,34,58,123,34,102,114,101,113,34,58,91,51,56,54,54,46,48,52,49,56,55,53,44,49,54,48,48,44,51,57,48,48,93,44,34,117,115,97,103,101,34,58,91,48,44,48,44,49,44,50,44,49,44,49,44,48,44,50,93,44,34,108,111,97,100,34,58,91,48,46,53,44,48,46,54,51,44,48,46,54,49,93,125,44,34,109,101,109,111,114,121,34,58,123,34,114,97,109,34,58,91,49,53,46,53,52,44,49,50,46,48,49,44,50,50,46,55,44,50,46,56,53,44,57,46,54,55,93,125,44,34,100,105,115,107,115,34,58,123,34,115,115,100,34,58,91,50,49,57,46,49,44,49,51,44,49,57,52,46,57,44,54,46,51,93,44,34,104,100,100,34,58,91,48,44,48,44,48,44,49,48,48,93,125,44,34,116,101,109,112,115,34,58,123,34,99,111,114,101,45,48,34,58,91,51,50,44,56,53,44,49,48,53,93,44,34,99,111,114,101,45,49,34,58,91,51,54,44,56,53,44,49,48,53,93,44,34,99,111,114,101,45,50,34,58,91,51,55,44,56,53,44,49,48,53,93,44,34,99,111,114,101,45,51,34,58,91,51,56,44,56,53,44,49,48,53,93,125,125,44,34,97,116,116,97,99,104,101,100,34,58,110,117,108,108,125]";
        final String expected = "{\"author\":\"Anton\",\"type\":\"server info\",\"date\":\"08/01/2021\",\"content\":\"\",\"opt\":{\"cpu\":{\"freq\":[3866.041875,1600,3900],\"usage\":[0,0,1,2,1,1,0,2],\"load\":[0.5,0.63,0.61]},\"memory\":{\"ram\":[15.54,12.01,22.7,2.85,9.67]},\"disks\":{\"ssd\":[219.1,13,194.9,6.3],\"hdd\":[0,0,0,100]},\"temps\":{\"core-0\":[32,85,105],\"core-1\":[36,85,105],\"core-2\":[37,85,105],\"core-3\":[38,85,105]}},\"attached\":null}";
        try ( final Reader reader = Decoding.of(new StringReader(payload));
                final Writer writer = new StringWriter() ) {
            CharStreams.copy(reader, writer);
            Assertions.assertEquals(expected, writer.toString());
        }
        try ( final Reader reader = Decoding.of(new JsonReader(new StringReader(payload)));
                final Writer writer = new StringWriter() ) {
            CharStreams.copy(reader, writer);
            Assertions.assertEquals(expected, writer.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Note that `CharStreams.copy` is taken from Google Guava from brevity.

The readers can now be consumed as regular JSON documents by library, `org.json`, Gson, Jackson, Moshi or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

Besides achieving this in Jackson as [demonstrated by Simeon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65633241/10902231) , you can achieve the same with **Gson**.

```
Map<String, Object> decode(final byte[] src) {
    final String srcString = new String(src);
    final Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(srcString, mapType);
}
```

In case you want to optimise the code and prevent anonymous inner classes, you can create a static inner class ...

```
private static class MapTypeToken extends TypeToken<Map<String, Object>> {}
```

... and use it in your `Type` variable ...

```
final Type mapType = new MapTypeToken().getType();
```